# Is this code vulnerable to XSS attacks?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

The question did arise from this one:
[Why does the browser modify the ID of an HTML element that contains &#x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519250/why-does-the-browser-modify-the-id-of-an-html-element-that-contains-x)

Given the following web page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // --------------------------------------------------------
      // could calling this method produce an XSS attack?
      // --------------------------------------------------------
      function decodeEntity(text){
        text = text.replace(/<(.*?)>/g,''); // strip out all HTML tags, to prevent possible XSS
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = text;
        return div.textContent?div.textContent:div.innerText;
      }
      function echoValue(){
        var e = document.getElementById(decodeEntity("/path/&#x24;whatever"));
        if(e) {
          alert(e.innerHTML);
        }
        else {
          alert("not found\n");
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="/path/&#x24;whatever">The Value</p>
    <button onclick="echoValue()">Tell me</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `id` of the `<p>` element contains characters that were escaped in order to prevent XSS attacks. The HTML part and JS part are generated by the server and the server inserts the same escaped value (which could origin from an unsecure source) on both parts.

The server escapes the following character ranges in the `&#x` format:

- 0x00 – 0x2D
- 0x3A – 0x40
- 0x5B – 0x5E
- 0x60
- 0x7B – 0xFF
- 0x0100 – 0xFFFF

In other words: the only characters that are *not* escaped are:

- 0x2E – 0x39 (`.`, `/`, `0123456789`)
- 0x41 – 0x5A (`A` – `Z`)
- 0x5F (`_`)
- 0x61 – 0x7A (`a` – `z`)

Now, I have to get access to that `<p>` through javascript. The function `echoValue()` in the referenced question always failed because the browser converts `&#x24;` to `$` in the HTML part but leaves it as `&#x24;` in the JS part.

So, [Gareth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1855592/gareth-cornish) came up with [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14519991/520162) that is simple and works.

My concern is that the possibility of an XSS attack that was eliminated by escaping the dynamic strings will arise again when using the `decodeEntity()` function provided in the referenced answer.

Could anybody point out whether there might be security concerns (**which?**) or not (**why not?**)?

Comment: Just make the server not escaping it inside the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I first suggest you have a look at the following links discussing HTML sanitation in JavaScript and XSS in Javascript:

- [Sanitize/Rewrite HTML on the Client Side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295566/sanitize-rewrite-html-on-the-client-side)
- [How to prevent Javascript injection attacks within user-generated HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942011/how-to-prevent-javascript-injection-attacks-within-user-generated-html)

**Security Lesson no 1:**
Don't reinvent the wheel. If something has been done before, chances are they did a better job than your ad hoc solution.

Even though I can't from the top of my mind find a way to exploit your simple regex I am not conviced it really captures all cases. The first link provides a solution that is more elaborated and has been reviewed and tested thoroughly.

I also suggest you look at [XSS Filter Evasion Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet). Shows you real good what kind of nasty things people might come up with.

Comment: Just an observation... both links are going to the same URL. Maybe that was not on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The extra constraints you're apply on the input may cause this attack to fail, but assuming arbitrary input to `decodeEntity`, here's an example of running script:

```
decodeEntity("<img onerror='alert(\"test\")'\nsrc='test'>")
```

This runs because `/<(.*?)>/` only matches if the `<` and `>` are on the same line.